# Como evitar formação automática de campo datetime em Mysql com Asp Net?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

Estou tentando ler campos datetime com MySql.Data.MySqlClient, só que o valor que retorna é sempre diferente do que está no banco,
por exemplo no banco esta 
"2002-05-01 00:00:00.000" mas o código retorna "5/1/02 12:00:00 AM" .
Código similar ao que estou usando abaixo, a diferença do oficial é o numero de campos que pego, agradeço qualquer ajuda.

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(con))
using (MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from tablename";
    connection.Open();
    var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (r.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r["dt_compra"].ToString());   // resultado 5/1/02 12:00:00 AM // aqui deveria ser 2002-05-01 00:00:00.000
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom você pode definir o  culture  info en-US  na sua aplicação mas  isso pode acarretar em  muitas  alterações como  formatação de moeda etc,  então  acho  que a melhor forma seria converter a data, mesmo  caso  você não  queira alterar as configurações  da applicação

Melhor forma

```
DateTime.Parse(r["dt_compra"].ToString(), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"))
```

Forma mais segura

```
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParse(r["dt_compra"].ToString(), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
```

Comment: Testei mas acontece a mesma coisa, é como se o mysql ja converte-se então no r["dt_compra"] ja vem a data com uma tentativa de conversao ai fica a string quebrada